# Jwplayer video not playing in Cordova Mobile application

Tags: android, cordova, jwplayer

I am trying to use jwplayer for playing video in cordova mobile application. Video is not playing because I am using the following tag in application head tag:

meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src *; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'">

Can anyone tell that without removing above tag, how can I play video in jwplayer.

Comment: have you tried this plugin https://github.com/moust/cordova-plugin-videoplayer

Answer (score 0):

Try with this one:

```html
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src *; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' https://cdn.jwplayer.com https://content.jwplatform.com https://ssl.p.jwpcdn.com; font-src https://prd.jwpltx.com; img-src https://prd.jwpltx.com">
```

**Notes:**

- You might have to add `media-src\ 'self'\ blob:
  whateverdomainthevideocomesfrom.com` to making videos to play
- Also, having `default-src *;` makes the CSP headers pretty
  useless as it opens far away too many possibilities for hacks. However, might ok since I have no knowledge how Cordoba Mobile apps are sandboxed.

**Tips:**

- <s>You can use this [firefox plugin](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/laboratory-by-mozilla/) and record a sample of the ideal CSP headers for app you are trying to apply them, while hitting record button and surfing the pages & using all its functionalities. e.g. playing videos</s>
- You can catch most of CSP violations using devtools, usually they apear on console and network tabs. If you click on the failed request, you can see what was the violation. Alternatively, setting `report-uri yourdomain.com/yourcspreportingscript.php` would be ideal, so you can get violations you might have missed and even hacking attempts.

These tips above are useless, unless you can open the Cordoba Mobile app on a desktop browser.